# Unclear on Live Preview, multisite, Craft 3.4

Tags: live-preview

My homepage is assembled from a set of entries, so creating Live Preview for a single one of those entries isn't helpful. I am unclear on how to create a Live Preview for all the entries in a section. I'd like it to work at the entry level, so the user can see a live preview of the entire page while editing a single entry contained in it.

- My entries do not have URLs
- Under **Preview targets**, I have *template_folder_name*/

Also, how do I need to alter my preview template so that it shows all the live entries as well as updates the appearance of the entry being edited in real time?

This seems to load my homepage, but without content. What am I missing?
[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of what you're trying to achieve, but afaik you can't generate a preview of content that doesn't have it's own slug. So perhaps add {slug} after `gsn/`?

Comment: Can you add the relevant Twig code (i.e. the template being rendered for the `/gsn` URL) to your question? Craft is actually smart enough to "swap out" entries being previewed with their draft states, so I suspect it's something in your template that prevents that behavior from working correctly.

Comment: Also, which Craft version are you using?